# Remotely view a live stream from the pi using 3g dongle

Tags: raspbian, camera, streaming-video, motion

I am trying to view the live video stream of a camera connected to the raspberry pi remotely. I have a 3g Dongle (wvdial) connected to the pi. Currently I am using motion software to do the live streaming and recording. I am able to view the live stream locally on a web browser of the pi. But, how do I view the stream remotely from anywhere using the same 3g dongle (without static IP) and camera? I need to stream this video to my web server too.

Comment: You're going to pay a lot for data charges if you plan on viewing or streaming to a web server directy from the Pi using 3G - Good discussion around using Dynamic DNS and routing thru another server at https://www.element14.com/community/thread/35336/l/dynamic-dns-for-3g-usb-modem-raspberry-pi?displayFullThread=true

Comment: You should try UV4L at http://linux-projects.org. It offers many streaming options, from end-to-end streaming to streaming from or to the cloud (Janus Gateway or Jiti Meet).

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

1) Contact service provider open port for your 3g because it is stay on locate network of router (managed by service provider) where connect to internet.

2) Build client (with java, i think you should use java media framework) on Raspberry Pi, connect camera and read video stream then post frame to server (static ip).